# Can I "inject" values from message resources into model objects before implicit Jackson serialisation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have a REST API built with Spring Boot / Spring MVC, using the implicit JSON serialization via Jackson.

Now, just before the implicit serialization, I would like to "inject" some UI texts from message resources into the objects that Jackson converts into JSON. Is there some neat, simple way to do this?

As a much simplified example, below I'd like to set `Section` title to a user-visible value, based purely based on its `SectionType`.

(Sure, I could hardcode the UI texts in SectionType, but I'd rather keep them separate, in resource files, because it's cleaner, and they might be localised at some point. And I can't autowire `MessageSource` in the entities / model objects which are not Spring-managed.)

```
@Entity
public class Entry {

     // persistent fields omitted

     @JsonProperty
     public List<Sections> getSections() {
         // Sections created on-the-fly, based on persistent data
     }

}

public class Section {    
    public SectionType type;
    public String title; // user-readable text whose value only depends on type       
}

public enum SectionType {
    MAIN,
    FOO,
    BAR; 

    public String getUiTextKey() {
        return String.format("section.%s", name());
    }
}
```

Somewhere in a `@RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/entry/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Entry entry(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return service.findEntry(id);
}
```

UI texts that I'd like to keep separate from code (`messages_en.properties`):

```
section.MAIN=Main Section
section.FOO=Proper UI text for the FOO section
section.BAR=This might get localised one day, you know
```

And what I'd like to do in a Spring-managed service/bean somewhere (using `Messages`, [a very simple helper](https://gist.github.com/jonikarppinen/0d600b0c82edce890310) wrapping a `MessageSource`):

```
section.title = messages.get(section.type.getUiTextKey())
```

Note that if I call `entry.getSections()` and set the title for each, it will not affect the JSON output, since the Sections are generated on the fly in `getSections()`.

Do I have to go all the way to custom deseriazation, or **is there a simpler way to hook into the model objects just before they get serialized by Jackson?**

Sorry if the question is unclear; I can try to clarify if needed.

Comment: You can try to write an aspect around every controller method, that returns Section.  After you call `joinPoint.proceed();` in the aspect, you will get the returned value from the controller and will be able to set the message (you can autowire in aspect). Not sure that it will work for Controllers... http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice

Comment: @Evgeni, can confirm that it should work. We do something similar.

Comment: @luboskrnac Yes it works, just tested it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment you can write an Aspect around every controller method that returns Section.

I wrote a simple example. You have to modify it with the message source.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public Person index(){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("evgeni");
        return person;
    }
}
```

Aspect

```
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class MyAspect {
        @Around("execution(public Person com.example..*Controller.*(..))")//you can play with the pointcut here
        public Object addSectionMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

            Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
            Person p = (Person) retVal; // here cast to your class(Section) instead of Person
            p.setAge(26);//modify the object as you wish and return it
            return p;
        }

    }
```

Since the aspect is also a `@Component` you can `@Autowire` in it.